# Logging in manually created userena user fails, why?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-users, django-userena

I want to be able to log in a manually created [Userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) user for testing:

From **my_app/test/test_views.py**

```
import django.test
from userena.models import UserenaSignup


class MyViewTestCase(django.test.TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        my_user = UserenaSignup.objects.create_user(username="my_name", email="my_name@gmail.com", password="my_password")
        log_in = self.client.login(username=my_user.username, password=my_user.password, email=my_user.email)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

In **pdb**:

```
>>> log_in
False
```

Why does logging in fail?

Comment: I have never used Userrena myself, but with some systems this might be due to user not clicking "Verify your email" link or some other extra limitations forced on the user account creation.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. This was the clue I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference:

**How to create a userena user manually**

```
>>> my_user = UserenaSignup.objects.create_user(username="my_name", email="my_name@gmail.com", password="my_password")

# A userena user that hasn't activated his account with an account confirmation link
# has False for is_active
>>> my_user.is_active
False
```

**How to activate an inactive userena user**

```
>>> active_my_user = UserenaSignup.objects.activate_user(my_user.userena_signup.activation_key)
>>> active_my_user.is_active
True
```

I found this bit of code [here](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/6bcc1e12ff07540212d15ec506d1d6c66a50ea16/userena/tests/managers.py#L62-L63), in the tests of Userena.

**How to login a userena user manually**

Logging in failed because only a user that has `True` for `is_active` can log in.
So after activating your user (see above) you log in as follows in a test:

```
self.client.login(username=active_my_user.username, password="my_password", email= active_my_user.email)
#True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `my_user.password` is crypted.
Try this:

```
self.client.login(username=my_user.username, password='my_password')
```

Comment: This also returns `False`

Comment: I removed `email=my_user.email` from my original response